# CasperJS fails to login using fill() method

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication, fill, casperjs

I am new to Casper JS and I am having issue with the `fill()` method to log into a site. 
In the debug output, I reach the url of the landing page which is supposed to be reached after I login. However, it then sends me to a blank page and breaks :

```
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false
```

I have tested the code below to log into facebook and it worked. I have also logged in successfully to the site in the example below using a Phantomjs version of the Casperjs code below. So the issue seems to be specific to login using Casperjs fill() method.

1) Here is the html (I made it anonymous for security purposes):

```
//login form
<form id="***id_form***" class="loginBox" method="post" action="https://***login_link***/">

// input login
<input id="IDToken1" type="text" value="" name="IDToken1">

// input password
<input id="IDToken2" type="password" name="IDToken2">
```

2) Here is my Casperjs code:

```
var start_url = 'https://***login_url***'

casper.start(start_url, function() {

    this.test.assertExists('form#***id_form***', 'form is found');
    this.fill('form#***id_form***', {
        'IDToken1': '***MY_ID***',
        'IDToken2': '***MY_PASSWORD***'
    }, true);
});

casper.run();
```

3) Here is the console output (I hid the urls):

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...

[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps

[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://***login_url***, HTTP GET

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***url***, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***url***, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://***url***"

[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities

[info] [phantom] Step 2/2 https://***url*** (HTTP 302)
PASS form is found

[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#***id_form***'

[debug] [remote] Set "IDToken1" field value to ***My_ID***

[debug] [remote] Set "IDToken2" field value to ***My_PASSWORD***

[info] [remote] submitting form to https://***login_link***, HTTP POST

[info] [phantom] Step 2/2: done in 1211ms.

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***login_link***, type=FormSubmitted, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***url***, type=FormSubmitted, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://***url***, type=FormSubmitted, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://***url***"

[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***url***, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***url***, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***landing_page***, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true

[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://***landing_page***"

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://***url***, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Kinda hard to tell what's going on with all of the censors in there. If you're not comfortable with sharing urls or ids, change them to something consistent that makes sense, otherwise there is no way to follow along with this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
casper.start(start_url, function() {
    this.waitForSelector('form#***id_form***', function() {
        this.fill('form#***id_form***', {
            'IDToken1': '***MY_ID***',
            'IDToken2': '***MY_PASSWORD***'
        }, true);
    }
});

casper.then(function() {
   ...
}
```